# What mathematical term for this kind of "solution functions"?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology, inverse

Let $F$ a function of two variables and $x,y,z$ complex variables.

Let an equation $F(x,y)=z$ be given. Then a function or multifunction (correspondence) $H$ with $x=H(y,z)$ does exist.

1.) What is the mathematical term for calling $H$?

2.) In which classes of functions can $H$ be calculated explicitly (symbolically / in closed form)?

I already know, for algebraic functions $F$ e.g., $H$ is also algebraic. An algebraic $H$ can be calculated in closed form if it can be presented by radicals or by other explicit representations (Bring radicals etc.).

$H$ is a solution of the equation. Is it a kind of inverse relations, a kind of projection, an evaluation map or what?

I need to name $H$ to talk about it in general.

Comment: I wrote an answer for 1.) at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143525/partially-inverting-a-function/4143626#4143626

Answer (score 1):

1. $H$ is the *explicit* function for $x$.
2. I have never seen a general theory of analytically invertible functions.

Comment: @IV_: is this condition necessary ?

Comment: @IV_: this is a sufficient condition. Is it necessary ?